# Styling lost on button upon user input/click.

Tags: php, css

I have button below that I'm trying to style via css. Unfortunately, with the user clicks the button, the styling disappears, and only reappears when the page is reloaded, after which, the styling is lost once again when the user clicks... etc, etc.

PHP

```
<?php
if ($users != $user->id && $users != '' && $user->id != '') 
{
    if ($followers == 'all') 
    {
    ?>
        <input type="button" name="unfollow" value="Unfollow" id="unfollow"  onclick="unfollowall(<?php echo $user->id . ',' . $users; ?>,'<?php echo $fBoardId; ?>');" />
    <?php
    } 
    else 
    {
    ?>
        <input type="button" name="followall" value="Follow All" id="followall" onclick="followall(<?php echo $user->id . ',' . $users; ?>,'<?php echo $fBoardId; ?>');"/>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

How do I get to having the button be constantly styled?

Comment: Mind pasting your Javascript?

Comment: Do you have two different styles set based on the two different ids (#unfollow and #followall)?

Comment: Do the followall() and unfollowall() functions manipulate the CSS in any way?